# Showing an EditText selection handle programmatically

Tags: android

Suppose I activate the `EditText` programmatically using `requestFocus`. Is it possible to somehow show the text selection handle (I mean the drop-shaped piece under the blinking cursor) at the same moment, otherwise than by sending fake touch events?

[image]

Comment: use `editText.setSelection(positionWhereYouWantToPutCursor)`

Comment: @sourabhkaushik its just move cursor, but not trigger visibility of drop-shaped piece under it.

Comment: @kiv_apple Hi, have you found a solution?